# Ajax call not working after move to AWS from GODADDY

Tags: php, ajax, amazon-web-services

I transfered my code to AWS-ubuntu server.
Previously my project was on godaddy space. I have also pointed domain and set SSL.

I imported SSL certificates and set rules in 'default-ssl.conf' file.

Domain point out is successful and also SSL is on. HTML code and php code works but ajax call is not working.

Code language is php, jquery AJAX, phpmyadmin

I wrote ajax call like :

```
$.ajax({url: "demo_test.php", success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }});
```

but ajax request status display 'pending' and not completed. After sometime, it displayed timeout.

Why this happened? can you please help me.

Comment: Do not enough information.

Comment: probably permission issue

Comment: i give 777 to entire folder,subfolder and files still not called@kenzotenma